# unable to access local storage through selenium with java script execute function. However same js code work work in console of browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
x=driver.execute_script("window.localStorage['devcid']")
```

using execute_script but it returns none when I print x
however, in the console of the browser, I execute same javascript it works
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkKy5.png i added image

Answer (score 0):

i was not using the return it should be like

```
x = driver.execute_script("return window.localStorage['devcid']")
```